# Fluently with NHibernate: reference other row in table by "parent_id" but return actual entity, not the id?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I was wondering if this is possible with Fluently in NHibernate. The scenario:

I have an entity looking something like this:

```
public class PairedEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

ParentId is mapped to other entity in the same table (it's a OneToOne mapping by id). Is it possible, to somehow make Fluently fetch paired entity as something like that:

```
public class PairedEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
    ...
    public UnitEntity ParentUnitEntity { get; set; } // <----
}
```

Basically what I want is to store in table the id of parent entity, and let Fluently fetch it for me as some kind of "shadow" property, loaded into ParentUnitEntity.

Comment: PairedEntity and UnitEntity are different classes. Is it an oversight or a reference to another Table?

Comment: It was a mistake, should be PairedEntity not UnitEntity. Anyway I've solved the problem. Not what I wanted in the end, but works more or less. I've added this to fluently map:

`References(x => x.ParentUnit).Column("parent_id").Nullable();`

Comment: Using NHibernate you don't need `ParentId` at all because `Parent.Id` is supported without loading the reference and more natural anyway, Also it removes the redundancy. As for assigning the reference with only an id, that's what `session.Load(id)` is for.